# Importing existing project from PIL to Pillow

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I've got a django (1.5.1) project. This project was built with PIL. Nowadays pip use only Pillow. 
I ran my virtualenv, cd to project folder, installed all requirements (PIL is changed to Pillow) and stacked with problem.

```
 >>python manage.py syncdb 
No local settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/watashi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/watashi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/watashi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/watashi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/home/watashi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/watashi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/home/watashi/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError utils: No module named Image
```

To solve this problem I also tried following by [this](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/porting-pil-to-pillow.html) tutorial, but it didn't help. What wrong with it? How to understand that problem?

Other information:

manage.py script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: It seems you're answering your own question: `This project was built with PIL. Nowadays pip use only Pillow.` (and the error is pretty straightforward: `No module named Image`)

Comment: Somewhere in your code you're using "import Image" -- that used to work with PIL, but when you're using Pillow, you have to do "from PIL import Image" or you will get what you're getting, an ImportError.

Comment: @achedeuzot Ok. Is that mean I should install Pil?

Comment: Two possibilites: install PIL and hope it works OK on your platform or update the code using PIL to Pillow.

Comment: @kchan Thank you. I'll try to search in this direction. I'm just a little tired about running project with plenty of errors. Probably that's why I'm asking such simple questions.

Comment: @achedeuzot Thank you. Well, finally we've got a simple disjunction. I'll try both.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be fixed by using the following command

**pip install --upgrade setuptools** .